# If/Then formula needed, with copy/paste to 3rd cell function

Tags: worksheet-function

I have one column which requires a "Yes or No response. If the user types in a "No", I need the content from another cell on the same row to be copied and pasted to a third cell on that row.

Is that possible, and if so, what kind of formula should I use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Copy/Paste is an application/environment function, not a datafile (worksheet) function. Please provide a detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, with examples, to ensure that those reading your question are understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you'll need in the 3rd cell (coulmn) the following fomula:

```
=IF(B1="No",A1,"")
```

See it here in action: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JhymoM4DcjaTgl48S